# Why memory access errors on 64-bit machine point to 32-bit address?

Tags: memory, cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit

Probably every one at least once in their computer lifetime came through an error like **Memory access violation at 0x8231d13f** which states the 32-bit address in memory where the violation occured. Let's say we have 8 GiB of RAM. The question is: *why on 64-bit CPUs machines those violation errors still address 32-bit value and not 64-bit one (eg. 0x1934a8bb34cf1200)? If computer still uses 32-bit then how it can access addresses when we got more than 4GiB of RAM (which can store more than 2^32 adresses)?*

First I thought it may have something to do with *address bus line* width but I read that current AMD architectures have those lines of 48-bit width.

Comment: The only reason a memory access violation would point to a 32-bit address, is if it the memory violation happened in a 32-bit process because a 32-bit application can only access 32-bit addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this
 [image]

are not provided by the operating system. It is up to the **program itself** to catch errors and display meaningful error information.

If the error is in a 32-bit executable, captured by a 32-bit only exception handler then there is nothing that the error dialogue *can* do but show a 32-bit address for the error location.

If it gets far enough that the operating system has to intervene in the process due to an access violation then it is likely to do nothing, ignore the request that caused an error, return the relevant error code to the application and expect *it* to deal with outputting an error message. This is not an operating system level feature. This is entirely the purview of the application.

If the program were a 64-bit executable, with 64-bit aware exception handling *then* I would expect to see a long address in the error window.

But even showing this kind of information in a dialogue box is, at best, pointless and useless. By the time you show this information it is basically beyond the point of no return. Some data has been lost, some critical unhandled state has occurred and chances are you've lost whatever it was doing.

Showing *any* address of error information to an end user is fiddling around while Rome burns. There is nothing the user can do about it, chances are that the address will be different with every invocation, and it's just dialogue box noise. You might as well just say "Sorry, something bad happened and we're exiting" and leave it at that.

Comment: Um, no. That error message IS provided by Windows, specifically by a default exception handler. It does this when no exception handler in the application's code provided an exception handler that dealt with the particular exception.